# SqlClient in Mono

Tags: c#, sql, ubuntu, mono

I am using mono in ubuntu and i need a web service to access an SQL database but in Mono when i use:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

The option SqlClient does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace is in the `System.Data` assembly. Try adding a reference to `System.Data`.

Mono documentation can be found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Data/

Comment: I added 

`using System.Data
 using System.Data.SqlClient;`

but in System.Data. the only option is System.Data.Design

Comment: Have you added an assembly reference to `System.Data`?

Comment: Thanks i added System.Data reference.

Comment: @AdriánSánchezAnderson If this answer solved your problem, please feel free to mark it as the answer to help others encountering the same issue find this Q/A.

Comment: To verify; adding System.Data fixes the problem